# Move toggle button to right

Tags: android, drawerlayout, drawertoggle

I want to set toggle button icon to right in my android app. here is my code. how I can do it?By the way I set the value of  `android:layout_gravity` to right and now I want to set the Drawer's icon to right, too. How I can do this?
My MainActivity's class code:

```
package com.examplde.menuefinal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends  ActionBarActivity {
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    String dokme_txt= "Esfandune";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dokmeha);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPlanetTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int post, long arg3) {
                String dokme_txt = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dokmeha)[post];
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"برروی "+dokme_txt+" کلیک شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        });
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(dokme_txt);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("تنظیمات");
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // tanzim e drawer toggle be surate DrawerListener baraye mDrawerLayout
        // emun
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following code, but min level API IS 17.
add this to your manifest application and activity tags

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

then after setContentView in mainActivity, add following. to make your hamburger icon on right side.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```